# show and hide div every 1min

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to show and hide div every 1min in jquery

Comment: Sounds like a high-tech, annoying blink tag.  Why?

Comment: don't - blinking things are really really annoying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give a look to the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval) core function and to the jQuery's [Effects/toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) function:

```
setInterval(function(){$('#myDiv').toggle();}, 60000);
```

Comment: doh beat me to it by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function() { $("#myDiv").toggle(); }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a timer plugin that you can use

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Timer

To flip show/hide, you can do something like this

```
<div id="mydiv">The div that you want to show and hide</div>

<script>
    $.timer(1000, function () {
        $("#mydiv").toggle()
    });
</script>
```

hope this helps!